# Mobile App: Data Update Notification

Tags: mobile, notification, data

I have a mobile app that displays simple data for a large set of items. The entire database is downloaded to the device (<5MB) on first run but requires updates in between source code updates.

**What is the best way to inform users of available/completed updates?**

Initial ideas:

1. Every launch, if an update is available ask user to update via popup
2. Download/install behind the scenes and inform users of new/updated info on next launch, in-app
3. Same as (2) but with a push notification

Pros/cons of each:

1. - Pro: User can decide when to download (Wi-Fi vs. 3G)
   - Con: Most users will never update, pop-up every launch could get annoying
2. - Pro: Seamless, always up to date
   - Con: Must open app to see updates
3. - Pro: User will be more inclined to open app and check updates
   - Con: Annoying if app is used infrequently

More info on the updates:

- Small, <100KB each
- Will occur, on average, 1-2 times per month
- Include new data and corrections on existing
- Will only remove data if it was initially incorrect

**Update**:

Some guidelines from [Android's notification design patterns](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html):

> Don't interrupt the user for low level technical operations, like saving or syncing information, or **updating an application**, if it is possible for the system to simply take care of itself without involving the user.

If I go with option (2) or (3) will I be violating this? Or is updating the *data* behind the app OK?

Comment: Interesting question. Can the application still be used if it doesn't get updated?

Comment: @JonW Yes, it will just be missing new data and corrections to existing info.

Comment: how large are the incremental updates on average?

Comment: @JeffH Updates are small, less than 100KB each.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the data I would go for either option two or three. 
If the application data is something I should act upon like email. I want push notifications to know that there is new information to act upon.

If I use it more to check up on things every now and then, like a RSS reader or facebook/twitter where I can miss updates or read them later without any downsides option three is probably better. I go to the application and get the nice surprise of new data.

Why would the user open the application? I think that's where your answer is.

To respect the users data connection, why not have an option: Only update on wifi []?

Comment: +1 purely for your final line, "respect the users data connection".

Comment: Is there a general size cut-off when WiFi downloads should be available?

Comment: I don't think I follow. As in, if the updates get to big, download them only on wifi? I don't think there's a general size cut off for that. Just by looking a myself. I'm okay with my streaming app, using ~100 mb/day. While I would be upset if facebook or similar used the same amount.

Answer (score 0):

Option 2 seems the least intrusive. If the user doesn't go to the app it means that they probably don't need too at the moment. If you believe users will get a big benefit of being notified, perhaps there can be an option in the settings where the user can provide the notification preference. I think having frequent notifications that don't provide an obvious benefit can cause users uninstalling the app completely and that's of course not a desired outcome :). Showing an update information when the app opens up could be fine too. If update is frequent than "Don't show it again" could be useful.